# Is there a workaround for this C4702 link-time warning?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I'm using boost::variant and am having trouble compiling in release mode. I am working in VC2010 with warning level 4 and warnings as errors. The code below compiles fine in debug mode, but in release mode I get a bunch of "Unreachable code" C4702 warnings emitted at link time (presumably I'm getting compiler warnings here because there is link time code generation when optimisations are enabled.)

Has anybody successfully disabled these warnings in this situation? I would prefer to keep the high warning level and warnings as errors if possible.

```
#pragma warning( disable:4702 )
```

... doesn't seem to work here. Here is some sample code:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

struct null{};
typedef boost::variant< null, double > variant_t;

class addition_visitor
: public boost::static_visitor< variant_t >
{
public:
    template< typename T, typename U >
    variant_t operator()( const T&, const U& ) const
    { 
        throw( "Bad types" );
    }

    variant_t operator()( const double& left, const double& right ) const
    {
        return variant_t( left * right );
    }
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    variant_t a( 3.0 ), b( 2.0 );
    variant_t c = boost::apply_visitor( addition_visitor(), a, b );
    return 0;
}
```

The warning is triggered by the templated operator(), which I'm using to catch attempts to apply the visitor to bad variant types.

Comment: Thumbs up for Warning level 4 + Warning as errors!

Comment: Have you tried putting the pragma at the top of the file, before the includes? And @Matthieu, absolutely, kills bugs before they show.

Comment: I have tried putting the pragma at the top of the file, around the class definition, around the apply_visitor call, and at the top of stdafx.h. None of these seem to work, unfortunately.

Comment: That's strange. I can reproduce the warning without the `#pragma warning( disable:4702 )`, but as soon as I put it in there (anywhere before the first `#include <boost/variant.hpp>`) it goes away. Are you using any other non-standard settings besides /W4 and /WX? I tried with and without LTCG, makes no difference, just works. Do you have SP1 installed by any chance? Because I don't.

Comment: Thank you. Inspired by your being able to compile this, I have had another look, and have been able to make this work by making one change: I disabled the precompiled header. Builds fine now. I'm not keen on doing without the precompiled header in my original project, but at least I have a work-around now.

Comment: This solution worked for me in VS2010: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380603/disable-warning-c4702-seems-not-work-for-vs-2012

Comment: Does the warning still exist if you enable the PCH again now? Perhaps you only had to rebuild the PCH (guessing adding the #pragma didn't trigger the rebuild or something like that)? Did you completely clear the output and rebuild all before?

Answer (score 1):

After a spot of lunch and a stroll, I've got an unsatisfying but functioning work-around. Instead of returning a variant from my visitor and throwing on error, I return a success boolean and store a result, thus:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

struct null{};
typedef boost::variant< null, double > variant_t;

class addition_visitor
: public boost::static_visitor< bool >
{
public:
    template< typename T, typename U >
    bool operator()( const T&, const U& )
    { 
        //throw( "Bad types" );
        return false;
    }

    bool operator()( const double& left, const double& right )
    {
        result = variant_t( left * right );
        return true;
    }

    variant_t result;
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    variant_t a( 3.0 ), b( 2.0 );
    addition_visitor v;
    if( !boost::apply_visitor( v, a, b ) )
    {
        throw( "Bad types" );
    }

    variant_t c = v.result;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why provide a body for the template operator at all?

I haven't got Boost handy here so I can't check for you, but the fact that the templated operator has a body most probably means that any and all calls, regardless of type, will compile fine, then throw an error at runtime.

Leave the body of the template operator out, and it will simply refuse to link when used with any other type than double.

Comment: The problem is that the type of a variant is determined at runtime. In this case, the variant actually holds a value from a market data stream, and the selection of values (and thus their types) is configurable. This visitor class might be applied to variants containing a null and a double, for instance, and I need to trap that. The compiler expects there to be a valid operator() for each pair of types in the variant template argument list; If I declare the non-double method but don't provide an implementation then I get an "unresolved external" linker error.

Answer (score 1):

The #pragma doesn't work because this is a link time not a compile time warning.

You could suppress the warning in release mode. I believe /ignore:xxxx on the linker command line will do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately the option to ignore linker errors has been removed from VC2010. Also, this is actually a compiler warning, generated (I reckon) by link-time code generation.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem in a Visual Studio 2012 MFC project; the same warning came from the *<memory>* header file, also during *Release* link time code generation.
I solved it by adding  *#pragma warning(disable:4702)*  early in the pre-compiled header file (*"stdafx.h"* in my case, just before *#including* STL header files).

Answer (score 0):

> If I declare the non-double method but
>   don't provide an implementation then I
>   get an "unresolved external" linker
>   error.

Try to add `inline` specifier at the template operator definition. Then MSVC shouldn't need its body compiling the class itself. So instead of `unresolved external` you'll be getting compile-time errors only when your code tries to use this template. As I understand - this is exactly what you want.

Comment: You might have been slightly misled by my simplified example code. In reality, I don't know the types of my variants at compile time. They contain prices from a live feed, some of which may be double, some null. Type checking is at run time, so at compile time I need to have (the boost::variant implementation and thus the compiler require) implementations of the visitor method for all possible combinations of contained type.

Answer (score 0):

Make the templated `operator()(...)` private and don't provide an implementation. That will catch the use of it at compile time instead of link time.

Comment: Variant type checking is at runtime (please see my comments and answer elsewhere) so failing to provide an implementation doesn't work.